# When do LINQ-to-SQL queries execute?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I just want to confirm...
LINQ-to-SQL queries never execute (hits the database) until it is enumerated, right?

Does anyone know if this is the same for LINQ-to-Entities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is called [Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they behave the same.

The query will be executed upon the first usage of the variable.